# xfdesktop (xfce4) broken? (can't set wallpaper)

Tags: desktop, xfce

On start-up, xfce4 loads lots of desktop pictures (I have the settings set to 'image list') one after another (about 10, but I have the feeling it gets more and more).
That by itself would be no problem, but then it decides to show no background image, just an awful shade of brown. Plus, it shows files (icons) on the desktop, which I don't want.

Where could I start to look to fix it?

Comment: have you tried reset the settings?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the icons:
right click on the desktop -> Desktop settings -> Icons -> Icon type -> None

Comment: no, that seems to get overriden

Comment: Could it be that there's Nautilus auto-starting?

Comment: yes, but why should this cause problems?

Comment: Nautilus tries to handle the desktop, so it overrides xfdesktop :) Try launching Nautilus with --no-desktop

Comment: no I don't have nautilus installed...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot somewhere?

Comment: no, I'd have to paste a gif from meanwhile about 30 images (background/droplist) that follow very fast, but weirdly it's stopped disabling the background (i.e, I now get a background image)

Comment: I have found in the task manager an accumulation (25 or so) of the process xf

Comment: ...the process xfdesktop --display :0.0 --sm-client and then a long number.

Comment: And this happens every time you reboot?

Comment: It seems to load one extra (-> +1) at every startup. I'd need some more reboots to verify this.

Comment: Odd... Try menu -> Settings -> Session and startup -> Session, quit every xfdesktop instance, then "Save session" and reboot

Comment: well, that worked, but I have a feeling that I'm only fighting the symptoms.

Comment: Yes, but it's still something :) Are there multiple xfdesktops after a few reboots?

Comment: not so far. I will call again if problems recur. thank you so far.

Answer (score 0):

Did you directly install xfce, or did you start with something like ubuntu (which installed GNOME by default) then switch over to it?

If you have, boot into your other desktop environment, and try turning off all desktop settings there.